# pgfplots: frame not closed for surface plot

Tags: pgfplots, 3d

If you compile this MWE you will find that the frame for the 2d plot is closed, but for the contour plot, which is a 3d plot, not. Both figures are taken from the examples from the pgfplots manual. How can I fix this?

```
\documentclass[
10pt
]{scrreprt}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{patchplots}

\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        xlabel=Cost,
        ylabel=Error
    ]
    \addplot[
        color=red,mark=x
    ] coordinates {
        (2,-2.8559703)
        (3,-3.5301677)
        (4,-4.3050655)
        (5,-5.1413136)
        (6,-6.0322865)
        (7,-6.9675052)
        (8,-7.9377747)
    };
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        title={$x \exp(-x^2-y^2)$},
        xlabel=$x$,
        ylabel=$y$,
        small,
        view={0}{90},
        width=10cm,
        height=5cm
    ]
    \addplot3[
        surf,
%        shader=interp,
        domain=-2:2,
        domain y=-1.3:1.3,
    ]{exp(-x^2-y^2)*x};

    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you are actually seeing a 3D box from above and not actually drawing a true 2D box. Hence the drawing order makes the line cornering different.

You can enforce a workaround via extending the axis lines by adding

```
axis line style = {shorten <=-0.5\pgflinewidth,shorten >=-0.5\pgflinewidth}
```

to the 3D plot axis options and that would look like a closed box.